# Angular Mat Form Field Input Underline Overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

I used angular material in my project. As you can see the first screenshot, there is no problem in the angular material. But after refresh the page, you will see in the second screenshot. The input bottom line comes over the input. And also I am using tailwind css in my project.

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G14c.png)

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g55Jk.png)

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>{{ username }}</mat-label>
  <input
    formControlName="newUser"
    matInput
    #newusername
    maxlength="256"
    [placeholder]="'New Username' | translate"
  />
  <mat-hint align="start">{{ newusername.value.length }} / 15 </mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="newUserInfo.get('newUser')?.touched">
    {{ "New Username" | translate }}
    <strong> {{ "Required" | translate }}</strong>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS code too? I recommend inspecting the elements and checking which class/CSS code is overriding the default form field.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem. The cause of the problem is that it mixes with the css in the other component. I solved the problem using with ::host director.